# in app purchase pop-up is clickable even when 'beginIgnoringInteractionEvents" is active

Tags: iphone, touch, uialertview

I'm showing custom indicator when user clicks a button to purchase an in-app item.

The custom indicator calls 'beginIgnoringInteractionEvents' on init.
However the apple provided in-app-purchase popup(to show item name/price) is still touchable.

Well, that's all good, but I tried adding another UIAlertview on the process(after user confirms the purchase and apple validates it), because the purchase process takes a while and it just seems boring with only being able to see indicator spinning.

Now the problem is, the UIAlertView I added is not touchable.
How is apple's alertview(in-app-purchase pop-ups) touchable and not mine?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The in app purchase box seems to count as a different process, separate from your app as it calls `applicationDidBecomeActive:` and `applicationWillResignActive:` similar to the text message box.

This would explain why it can receive touches, but views internal to your app can't

Comment: Webster; Thank you for explanation, can you suggest me a alternative overal strategy for me to add a clickable UIAlertView then?

Comment: Could you call 'setUserInteraction:NO' on the views you dont want the user to be able to touch instead of disabling all touches?

Comment: Webster, would it disable touches to all the behind views?

Comment: UIAlertViews don't allow interaction behind them as default.